# delete cookies on session timeout in java

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, cookies, web.xml, logout

I am developing a java web application in which I have configured `session-timeout` to be equal to 4 minutes.This application also uses cookies.

My problem is after 4 minutes of inactivity the HttpSession expires but the cookies remain in the browser (age is set to -1). Is there any way to delete cookies after session timeout?

P.S.  setting cookie age equal to 4 minutes wont help.cookies should be deleted after 4 minutes of **inactivity** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the cookie age to 4 minutes, and reset the cookie age every time your server sends a response, then the cookie will time out after 4 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Do you mean for every request i should write a filter?

Comment: It would entirely depend on how you are using the cookies.

Comment: @Shurmajee  I am also trying to figure out the way to delete the cookies after inactivity by some minutes. Do you mind sharing how did you resolve this?

Comment: It has been years. I did end up relying on session timeout for this. You may write custom code in JS to do this, however, there would always be some cases where your code will not run successfully. for example, a browser/system crash. The best way is to invalidate the session on the server side.