# Remove a Cookie inside the HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies

I have a situation where I need to create a cookie when a session is created, and when the session is removed I have to remove the cookie. When a user manually ends a session I can remove the cookie in the doGet method of the logout servlet. But when the session times out I am not able to do that, so I am planning to sue the HttpSessionListener for this, but I have seen some where that we cannot do that. Is there any other way than the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582689/delete-cookies-on-session-timeout-in-java).

Comment: Why don't you just associate cookie's data as attribute of `HttpSession` itself instead of attempting to reinvent it?

Comment: I actually need to share the http session across applications. But since that is not possible I am forced to sue cookie.

Comment: Across applications on same (sub)domain? You can just configure the session cookie path in web.xml and/or session cookie domain in server config.

Comment: Sorry Dint get your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Really how do want to remove a cookie when you do not access to the user?!?!

The only solution is setting cookie live-time to the exact time your cookie session is(1 hour is default)

For each request you need to set the cookie with the updated time(`current_timestamp+'1 hour'`), it will tell browser keep the cookie for next 1 hour.

Beside the cookie, you need to check the integrity of the cookie and the session, simply track the cookie integrity with the session(maybe a hash), it helps you when a user tries to fool your server, by providing cookie A from user A by session user B.