# Under what circumstances does a session variable die?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables

I want to use a session variable to store some data in my mvc 4 application but I'm a little unsure of the sessions life cycle. I have the timeout set and obviously it dies when that runs out but I'm curious as to what happens (and how I can control what happens) when:

- The browser closes
- Page is refreshed
- User logs out (I'm assuming I need to deal with this one manually)

Comment: The session will survive all of them, in the second case the timeout starts with 0 again.

Comment: What type of `SessionStateProvider` are you using?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you. So by setting it to a new instance when my app starts will the timeout restart each time as well?

Comment: @aw04 If you don't know, chances are you are using the default `InProc` SessionStateProvider which will store session within the memory address space of the running application. When the Application Pool is recycled, Session will be lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think aside from all the comments (which I think are all answers), the (other) key item to think about is that at the *client side* (browser), sessions are *cookies*. So if for example I set my browser to discard cookies each time I close it, that will "break" sessions.

Obviously, this doesn't apply to *cookieless sessions* (where the "identifier" is in the URL).

Also, look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3737345/304683) on *persistent* and *non-persistent* cookies (where a browser close, aka "browser session", will dump sessions).

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.ASPX):

> ASP.NET must track a session ID for each user so that it can map the user to session state information on the server. **By default, ASP.NET uses a non-persistent cookie** to store the session state. However, if a user has disabled cookies on the browser, session state information cannot be stored in a cookie.
>
> ASP.NET offers an alternative in the form of cookieless sessions. You can configure your application to store session IDs not in a cookie, but in the URLs of pages in your site. If your application relies on session state, you might consider configuring it to use cookieless sessions. However, under some limited circumstances, **if the user shares the URL with someone else—perhaps to send the URL to a colleague while the user's session is still active—then both users can end up sharing the same session**, with unpredictable results.

That said, and depending on the type of data you want to *persist* for x time, you can also look into client side storage options (e.g. [*web/dom/local storage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), etc.) in addition to/conjunction with or even perhaps a replacement to, *server/cookie based storage*. Note still, that this isn't "immune" to client/user action (user can dump all that data if/whenever they want to), nor any **security** implications.

Comment: Thank you. The link was especially helpful.